# Is there a way to search for an exact keyword in a file in C?

Tags: c, file, whitespace, keyword

By an exact keyword, I mean one that is expressed as a single word, starting and ending with a white-space character(either a *space*, *tab*, or *newline*). I don't want to return words that are just containing my keyword as a substring.

Below is my attempt at finding and printing lines from a text file which contain an exact keyword. Is there an easier way? My current attempt doesn't work because I don't know how to ignore lines containing my keyword as a substring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINESIZE 1024
#define MAXKEYWORD 256

int main()
{
  FILE* file = fopen("yankee.txt", "r");
  int linenumber =0;
  char keyword[MAXKEYWORD];
  char keywordline[MAXLINESIZE];

  while ((fscanf(file, "%[^\n]%*c", keywordline)) != EOF)
  {
      linenumber++;
      strcpy(keyword,"a");
      if(strstr(keywordline,keyword))
        {
          printf("linenumber = %d\n'%s'\n\n",linenumber,keywordline);
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**the text file**

```
Yankee Doodle went to town
riding on a pony
Stuck a feather in his cap
And called it macaroni.
```

**So, the output should be:**

```
linenumber = 2 
'riding on a pony'

linenumber = 3
'Stuck a feather in his cap'
```

Comment: `fscanf` can read "words", just `fscanf("%s"`

Comment: Unrelated: you don't need to `strcpy()` inside the loop. Once, outside the loop, is enough.

Comment: I recommend that you use `fgets` to read full lines instead. And then something like `strtok` to "tokenize" the string on space. Do that inside a loop, and use `strcmp` to find the "keyword".

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to run `strstr()`, then check if the characters surrounding the hit are whitespace or whatever counts as a word separator, or start/end of text.

Something like:

```
char *p = strstr(text, key);
if (p) {
    if (p == text) {
        /* match at start of text */
        startok = 1;
    } else if (isspace(*(p-1)) {
        /* whitespace before the match */
        startok = 1;
    }
    /* same for end */
}
```

Just make sure to check you don't try to read past the start/end of the string.